# Rspec + factory_girl infinite loops due to class diagram?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have simple rspec tests such has this one:

```
describe Flow do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    create(:flow).should be_valid
  end
end
```

with a factory_girl like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :flow do
    association :source
    ...some other associations...
  end
end
```

Now, when i run this and look at rspec's log, there is a sequence of sql instructions that loops forever and ever (> 2 hours). The loop is exactly the same and repeated over and over again, with only some value changing due to `sequence()` fields in the factories.

I know my class diagram is loopy, meaning that a class A associates with a class B that associates with a class C that associates with a class A.

Could this be the source of this "infinite"(maybe it ends at some point) looping or it is normal behavior? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: I see two potential reasons. 1) you create an association to `flow` in `source` 2) you have some before or after filter in your model causing the trouble

Comment: Well, I **know** I have an association to `flow` in `source` but through other associations. Is there anyway I can do to still be able to run rspec tests? (btw: the test just finished with a `stack level too deep` error)